# Cornucopia: Can Horn of Plenty be used together with normal treasure cards?

Tags: dominion, dominion-cornucopia

I recently bought Dominion: Cornucopia and we played our first game yesterday. Something that confused me was the *Horn of Plenty* card which has a treasure value equal to the number of different card titles you have in play at that moment.

From the rule book I understood that if you'd first use other treasure cards to buy a card from the stock and then play Horn of Plenty(assuming you'd have more than one buy action), Horn of Plenty would take into account the treasure cards.

But in case I'd have only one buy option, am I allowed to play Horn of Plenty together with other treasure cards and let them count towards the total of Horn of Plenty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Horn of plenty doesn't give you money, it lets you gain a card costing up to the number of different named cards you have in play.

[image: Horn of Plenty]

This means you should always play it after your other treasures, you then gain a card from Horn of Plenty. Afterwards you then do your buys as normal. Horn of Plenty doesn't use up a buy or any coins. If you don't want to buy anything afterwards, you don't have to. Playing treasures gains you coin to spend, it doesn't obligate you to buy something with them!

Comment: Note that you have to play all treasures before buying any cards. You cannot play some treasures, then buy a card, then play Horn of Plenty. Also, there are some reasons you may wish to play treasures AFTER playing Horn of Plenty (like Bank).

Comment: @GendoIkari It helps to point out *why* this is important, such as when a player is buying a Mint (which trashes all treasure cards currently in play).